# Using ftrace in linux to understand nvme linux driver

Tags: linux, driver, ftrace, nvme

I am new to linux. I am trying to use ftrace to understand linux nvme driver code flow. Based on articles in net, once my nvme device is mounted, I am issuing following commands to get the trace

1. cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
2. cat /dev/nvme0n1 >  trace (sudo nvme list shows up the nvme device nvme0n1)
3. echo nvme_queue_rq > set_graph_function (nvme_queue_rq from nvme driver is called when we issue IO )
4. echo function_graph > current_tracer
5. echo 1 > tracing_on
6. nvme write /dev/nvme0n1 -s0 -c63 ( issue write cmd using nvme cli)
7. echo 0 > tracing_on
8. cat /dev/nvme0n1 >  trace
9. cat trace

But nothing gets appended to trace file. Is there anything additional I have to do to ensure the function calls are rightly captured.
Is there any alternate way to capture the function calls of linux nvme driver?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello! You may want to ask on unix & linux site instead https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `cat /dev/nvme0n1 > trace` is copying the contents of the disk to file trace.  Did you mean echo?

Comment: @stark. Yes its echo. the file is empty

Comment: Your usage of ftrace sounds not correct, you should not do any cat into the `trace` file, according to https://lwn.net/Articles/365835/. Tools like `trace-cmd` or `perf trace` may be more convenient way to start using ftrace, and Gregg has some example tools based on ftrace to trace I/O, https://lwn.net/Articles/608497/ http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-16/iosnoop-for-linux.html https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/examples/iosnoop_example.txt (and for monitoring other parts of the kernel - http://www.brendangregg.com/overview.html)